# Why is the TargetNullValue of a ContentControl in an ItemsControl shared between the items?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, itemscontrol, mahapps.metro

Given this xaml:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:IDeviceViewModel}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Margin="5"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1">
                        <ContentControl.Content>
                            <Binding Path="CurrentState">
                                <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                                    <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ActivateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type mah:MetroWindow}}}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                        <Button.Template>
                                            <ControlTemplate>
                                                <Image MaxWidth="100"
                                                       Margin="10"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                       Source="/Resources/ActivateDevice.png" />
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Button.Template>
                                    </Button>
                                </Binding.TargetNullValue>
                            </Binding>
                        </ContentControl.Content>
                    </ContentControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The "Activate-Device"-button defined in the `TargetNullValue` is shown only for the last item in the list. The other items are just shown blank, not even the default "Some.Namespace.SomeViewModel" text for a view model without data template. It doesn't matter what I put into the `Devices` collection, I always only see the button on the right-most (i.e. last) item.

I have no idea why?

Edit: it looks like the `TargetNullValue` is created only once and then "reused" for each item, so that it's "stolen" from the previous item. If that's the case, how can I prevent that? I want a new instance of the button to be created for each item.

Edit: the @KeithStein solution works:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <Button x:Key="ActivateDeviceButton"
                    x:Shared="False"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.ActivateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type mah:MetroWindow}}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=deviceRoot}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image MaxWidth="100"
                               Margin="10"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Source="/Resources/ActivateDevice.png" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:IDeviceViewModel}">
                <Grid x:Name="deviceRoot">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Margin="5"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentState, TargetNullValue={StaticResource ActivateDeviceButton}}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

So the question is now: why was the `TargetNullValue` shared in the first place?

Comment: One idea: put the `Button` in a `ResourceDictionary` with `x:Shared='False'`. Then reference the resource using 'StaticResource`.

Comment: @KeithStein this actually works! And it gives a concise syntax, too, as the binding can remain an attribute. Yet, I'd really like to understand _why_ wpf does this in the first place. I mean, I'd expect the data templates of the individual items in the items control to be instantiated independently, how can they share the target null value of a binding inside a content control inside each item's instance?

Comment: Great. I've posted it as an answer you can accept. As for why this is the case: I do expect that each of the items have their own individual instance of the `DataTemplate`, but maybe it's possible that the values those properties are set to are reused? So each separate `TargetNullValue` gets assigned the same `Button` that was already parsed. This works fine for `String`s or or other value types (which are most commonly used) and saves time and memory, but causes a problem for most other classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`x:Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-shared-attribute) attribute tells WPF to create a new instance every time an XAML element is used, but this can only be set on items in a `ResourceDictionary`. Try putting the `Button` in a `ResourceDictionary` with `x:Shared='False'`, then referencing it using `StaticResource`.